# Comma in sentences with 'since'

Tags: punctuation, commas

What do you know about the comma used in the sentence with a 'since'?
If the structure of a sentence is "Since (Noun + Verb)   (Noun + Verb)"
How's right?

- Since (Noun + Verb)**,** (Noun + Verb)
- Since (Noun + Verb) (Noun + Verb)

Comment: Can you give a more specific example or two?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it useful to use a comma because the **since** clause is a separate qualifying thought/idea:

> Since the beginning of time,  day will follow night
>   Since he started running, he's lost weight

It is also a natural place to ***take a breath*** when speaking/reading which usually signifies a good place for a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The word "since" is a conjunction introducing a coordinating clause in the structures presented by the OP; "**since + subject + verb**" forms a subordinating clause.

According to grammar, when a subordinating clause with "since" comes before a main clause, you put a comma after the subordinating clause.  So the first structure i.e. "since + noun + verb, noun + verb" is correct, whereas the other structure without comma isn't correct.  Look at the following sentences in the first pattern:

> Since Adam is going, Peter is going, too.
>
> Since you've finished your homework, you may go out and play.

Answer (score 0):

'Since' at the beginning of a clause indicates a subordinating clause. However, the order of the clauses does matter.

Subordinating clause, + Independent clause = use comma

Independent clause + Subordinating clause = no comma

**Example**

Since it is Christmas, I will buy my Mum a present.

I will buy my Mum a present since it is Christmas.